# What is the difference between program slicing and taint analysis?

Tags: binary-analysis, program-analysis

I'm studying program slicing and taint analysis. I know notion of program slicing and taint analysis.

I think Program slicing and taint analysis are similar notion.
I don' know difference between program slicing and taint analysis.

What is the difference between program slicing and taint analysis?

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding there are two major differences:

**Program Slicing** creates a reduced representant of a program which should still produces the same output for a given input. So you reduce the given program to its core functionality and you throw away all the clumpy/insignificant attachments.

In contrast a **Taint Analysis** traces the path of an information through an application and observes all the objects which are affected/visited/influenced by the corresponding information. Therefor a specific input is labeled or tagged, so it could be tracked during its execution.

So you have *a reduced representation of a program* with consideration of input output behavior VS the *trail of a selected input/variable* within a program and its dependencies.

---

See also detailed descriptions below:

**Program slicing** tries to reduce a given program `P` to a minimum form, a so called slice `S`, which produces the same behavior. More formally taken from these [slides](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~weile/cs513x/5.DependencySlicing.pdf):

> - produce a slice `S` from a given program `P` by deleting statements
> - slice must be syntactically correct a given set of variables `V`
> - should produce the same output when given to `S` and `P`

**Taint analysis** can be seen as a form of Information Flow Analysis. A more formal definition ripped from [here](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~weile/cs513x/5.TaintAnalysis1.pdf):

> Information flows from object x to object y, denoted x→y , whenever
>   Information stored in x is transferred to, object y.

Comment: IMHO, what you are referring is about "static program slicing". On the other hand, in terms of "dynamic slicing" which is performed on a execution trace, then it cares about a selected input as well (since one trace corresponds to one input).

Comment: Could you provide a reference for static vs dynamic slicing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they are essentially the same, with slightly different focus:

*Program slicing* is, strictly, extracting *code* that operates on specific variables/memory, while omitting all other code;

*Taint analysis* is tracking which *other* variables/memory are affected, via that code, by the ones you chose. Also, tainted data is usually stricter defined as "user-controllable data", while slicing can be done on any var.